# Is there a way to prevent JFrame from resizing when you call pack() in java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to make a program, and I want it to start out maximized, but I also want to be able to resize it. The only problem is that, whenever I call `frame.pack()`, it snaps back to the size I set it when I called `frame.setExtendedState(int)` which I made `java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH` so as to make the frame maximized when I first open it. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: What happens when you don't call pack?

Comment: just dont call pack - why do you have to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and I want it to start out maximized,

That is a one time setting of the state which can be changed at any time.

So you should be able to use:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
frame.pack();
// or pack() / setExtendedState(...)
```

That will not prevent the user from clicking on the maximize icon later if they desire to do so.

Answer (score 0):

maximized and resizable,

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

            final Timer tt = new Timer(68, e -> {
                Dimension r = f.getSize();
                f.setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.NORMAL);
                f.pack();
                f.setSize(r);
            });
            tt.setRepeats(false);
            tt.start();

            f.setVisible(true);

        });

    }
}
```